# Need a word or idiom or ecological term that describes vicious competition between humans or animals. Something like "reservoir dogs"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I need a phrase that describes an environmental condition or species' behavior that results in struggle for survival amongst groups or individuals. Or just a good idiom for competition. Basically just need a synonym of "reservoir dogs".

I want to use it to describe the struggle/competition between the many early hominins 45,000 years ago

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 'It's a dog eat dog world'

Comment: Do you want something slangy or something more scientific? Where do you want to use it?

Comment: Kilkenny cats. Also crab bucket.

Comment: crab bucket is exactly the type of thing I'm looking for except I'd rather a mammal be used cus I want to use it to describe the struggle/competition between the many early hominins 45,000 years ago and I feel like a mammal translates better

Answer (score 0):

> "Survival of the fittest" is a phrase that originated from Darwinian evolutionary theory as a way of describing the mechanism of natural selection.
> — Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

A much-quoted phrase from the poem 'In Memoriam A.H.H.' by the British poet Alfred, Lord Tennyson, published in 1850, is

**nature, red in tooth and claw**,

found in Canto 56, where it is metaphorically used of humanity.

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Memoriam_A.H.H.#:%7E:text=Another%20much%2Dquoted%20phrase%20from,And%20love%20Creation%27s%20final%20law)]

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/red_in_tooth_and_claw) has:

> *red in tooth and claw* [phrase]
>
> Involving savage or merciless conflict or competition.
>
> example sentences [metaphorical and literal usages; selected]:
>
> - *It is a war of each against all, nature red in tooth and claw.*
> - *Moreover, if left on their own, millions upon millions of animals would die more brutal deaths at the hands of a nature red in tooth and
>   claw.*
> - *Nature has always been a battle, red in tooth and claw.*
> - *While they destroy smaller traders by uncompetitive means, the superstores' relations with each other are not quite as red in tooth
>   and claw as their advertising suggests.*